# Can I directly dial phone numbers from Evolution's address book?

Tags: evolution, contacts, phone

Is there a way to directly dial phone numbers from Evolution's address book? I have an ISDN phone on my desk connected via USB. I've written a shell script that uses a phone number on the command line and then dials this number. The missing step is the integration into Evolution's address book.

Previously I've used Thunderbird where there is a click-to-dial extension. The address book shows the phone numbers as links and a script is executed when you click on one.

Does something like this exist for Evolution or something like it?

Comment: The mozilla extension is probably http://www.netdirect.ca/downloads/mozdial

Comment: Did you try gnome-phone-manager? It comes with evolution integration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome-phone-manager has evolution built in so if the phone is connected right it should fix your problem.